# How to pass variable value to gpg commands

Tags: php, encryption, command, gnupg

```
$importkey = system('gpg --import newkey.asc . $username');
```

need to pass the file name as a variable.so that file name with its contents can be import in gnupg keyring.

```
$gpg = system('gpg --recipient userid  --output filename --armor  --encrypt filename to encrypt', $retvalue);
```

how can i pass the recipient email id(userid) and the filename as variable to gpg commands

thanks!

Comment: Don't shell out. Use a proper API: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php

Comment: Need to do it using system call and php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ' to " for example and then you can pass in variables:

```
$importkey = system("gpg --import newkey.asc . $username");
```

Comment: Change the ' to "  -what you want to suggest please explain

Comment: Use double quotes (") instead of single quotes ('). Look at my example and yours and spot the difference.

Comment: Construct the command in a string and then supply this to the system command. Give us the value for this string to debug. For example: $cmd=""gpg --import newkey.asc . $username";print($cmd); $importkey=system($cmd);